# Jquery UI Range Slider to hide a row in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm implementing a Jquery UI range slider to the HTML table to hide certain rows.

I've created the below functionality with no success.

What I want is to **"hide particular raw in which any 'column 3' contains value less than 5"**

Jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aliakram/5TTm4/2098/).

1. The HTML is:

   ```
   <div id="slider"></div>

   <table id="slider" border=1>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>Release</td>
   <td>Rating</td>
   <td>Country</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>GoodFilm</td>
   <td>2013</td>
   <td>9</td>
   <td>USA</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>BadFilm</td>
   <td>2014</td>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>USA</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   ```
2. Javascript is:

   ```
   $("#slider").slider(
   {
           value:1,
           min: 0,
           max: 10,
           step: 1,
           slide: function( event, ui ) { 
   $("slider").find("td:nth-child(3)").filter(function () {
   return parseInt($(this).text()) <5; 
   }).parent().hide();
   ```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/2100/

1. you have DIV and TABLE with same id=slider. Change TABLE id to "slider_table"
2. in event "slide" change **$("slider").find** ... to **$("#slider_table").find**

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Hide A Raw</h1>

<div id="slider"></div>
<table id="slider_table" border=1>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Release</td>
            <td>Rating</td>
            <td>Country</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>GoodFilm</td>
            <td>2013</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>USA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>BadFilm</td>
            <td>2014</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>USA</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JQ:**

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value: 1,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#slider_table").find("td:nth-child(3)").filter(function () {
            return parseInt($(this).text()) < 5;
        }).parent().hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. But, when you move the slider towards 10, I want the hidden column to appear again without refreshing. (dynamically). Should I add any additional code/s for that? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to appear or hide rows based on the rating?

Comment: honestly, the table should dynamically change (without refreshing) when you move through the slider. When the slider value is less than 5, it should hide and if its more than 5, it should appear. Thanks!

Comment: this is awesome. It works. But, when I use it my PHP webpage, the first example (only hiding) is working. But, not the dynamic one. Actually I'm getting the table data from MySQL. I pasted the <script> at the bottom with other script files. Thank you very much friend.

Comment: how you add new rows? with ajax?

Comment: I'm not using Ajax. It shows and hides the raw "Richard" only. But, It has to show and hide, raws "Robert" and "Steven" as well. All of them contain value less than 5.  Thanks. [Sample PHP Table](http://versatalis.net/slider/)

Comment: I made a mistake. $('tr').show(); should be outside each function. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/2106/